# my application crashes when using sql cipher

Tags: android, sqlcipher

i am using sql cipher([sql cipher for android](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/)) in my app and it work well with android tablets and also with version above android 2.3 .But it crashes in android 2.2 version .can any one know about this problem and if yes please give me a solution.I have included the crash log

> 03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069): info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteException: not an error
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1870)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:863)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:183)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
>   03-24 05:04:26.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15069):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3):

> SQLCipher for Android depends on localization data from the ICU project. On Android platform version 2.3 and above SQLCipher for Android will attempt to use system provided ICU localization data. If you are attempting to use SQLCipher for Android on a supported platform below 2.3, the assets/icudt44l.zip needs to be included in your application as a dependency.

from https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/30

You can get that zip file directly at https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/raw/master/assets/icudt46l.zip if you don't have it in your SQLCipher installation

Comment: i have included the icudt44l.zip in the assets folder .but the crash still exists .did i have to do any extra code after including icudt44l.zip in assets folder?

Comment: Do you mean the icudt46l.zip?  Also have you followed the README - the one in the 1.1.0 release looks good.

Comment: @ louielouie i just copy and paste  icudt44l.zip to assets folder is that enough? or do i need  any extra work after that?

Comment: @Sujiz you need to include icudt46l.zip, are you using that?

Comment: @Stephen Lombardo yes i am using the same.first i use the icudt44l and now i use icudt46l.zip from the folowing link https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/tree/master/assets

Answer (score 1):

One curious thing I discovered on this matter. As detailed in this post: http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/ versions below Android 2.3 cannot read the icudt46l.zip file as it is larger than 1mb. The solution is to tell aapt (or proguard should you be using it) not to compress any .zip files.